# Retrieving a json array from a cakePHP controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, controller

I want to return a JSON array from a cakePHP controller. I effectively have a jquery click event which should send either a post, ajax or get call to the controller (specified with URL) and that controller should just return the array. This makes sense to me because I will not create a view file, I literally send the response to the controller and I can set the header, echo the json array and possibly just exit.

My output only says "Array" on console, and does not echo out any parameters in the array. Any ideas?

```
// jQuery code:
$("selector").click(function() {
      $.post("/controller/view/param1/param2/",function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      } 
}

// code in my controller:
public function view($param1 = false, $param2 = false) {
       $array = array("Name" => "John");
       header("Content-type: application/json");
       echo $array;
      exit;
}
```

EDIT: Found the solution - the **echo $array** must be **echo json_encode($array)**

Comment: Haha oopsie, found the solution :) I had to add *json_encode($array)* and cannot just echo the $array. If anyone else has good tips or ideas please send them for future reference and tips

Comment: Exactly. Is there a reason you are using "POST" if not sending anything? It takes 2 requests to do a post, while only 1 using GET/LOAD etc. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function view($param1 = false, $param2 = false) {
       $array = array("Name" => "John");
       header("Content-type: application/json"); // not necessary
       echo json_encode($array);
      exit;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned above, you cannot just echo an array (stupid mistake by me), you have to use the PHP function json_encode which will encode the array into a json object so that javascript can use it.

Comment: it would be cleaner to let the response object take care of sending headers - assuming cake2 (which Mauritz unfortunately forgot to mention)